# Error in MySQL Syntax :MySQL server version

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to insert values using mysql in nodejs. I had written the following code and installed MySQL support via npm, But cannot `INSERT INTO` the table due to this problem.

My code;

```
create: (data, callBack) => {
    pool.query(
      `insert into position(title,group,level,payScale,totslPost) values(?,?,?,?,?)`,
      [data.title, data.group, data.level, data.payScale, data.totalPost],
      (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
          return callBack(err);
        }
        return callBack(null, result);
      }
    );
  },
```

error on Postman:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Couldn't create the position",
    "error": {
        "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
        "errno": 1064,
        "sqlState": "42000",
        "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'position(title, group, level, payScale, totalPost) values('Jr. IT Consultant','C','L' at line 1",
        "sql": "insert into position(title, group,level, payScale, totslPost) values('Jr. IT Consultant','C','L-1','18,000-56,900',33)"
    }
}
```

Using api i'm trying to insert data into database